What happens to preinstalled windows when you swap drives between two laptops?
Ive got this new laptop with only 128gb of storage and I want to replace that disk with the 1tb disk from my current laptop with everything on it. My current laptop originally came with a 256gb drive that I cloned to this new 1tb drive and the original drive hasnt been touched since. So I want to put the original drive back into my current laptop, give it to someone else and start using the new one. Im assuming that preactivated windows licences are stored in bios of both laptops. What will happen if a disk that came from a laptop with a specific licence in bios is placed into a laptop with a completely new licence?
Both devices are lenovo thinkpads using windows 10pro and the new one is completely wiped.
Older laptop is lenovo yoga 370 with intel i5 8gb ram and the new one is lenovo yoga x13 that has intel i7 with 16gb.

(Clarity is needed because wording in this instance matters.) License keys are attached to the motherboard hardware ID. If it's only the drive itself without the OS from the other machine, nothing needs to be done - clean install Windows. If the drive has the OS from the other machine, this cannot be done without first generalizing the OS on the drive on the machine it's currently installed in  prior to installing on the new machine (see my comments here)

Once Windows 10 is installed on a system it will automatically be activated in the future. Since you have a OEM license your Windows 10 license has a digital entitlement. Cloning the HDD isn't necessary unless you want to clone the personal data. A clone of one OEM system loaded onto another OEM system will result in an installation that will not be activated unless specific steps are taken. It's more trouble then it's worth.

@Ramhund Windows can't be cloned between differing machines without generalizing the OS first. Windows will run if you do so, it will not run well, random issues will occur, as does performance degradation, due to an entirely incorrect set of critical, uninstallable OEM drivers, such as vital CPU chipset drivers. The effect of running the incorrect chipset drivers is even more pronounced on laptops since the chipset drivers affect many more things on a laptop. Generalizing removes the oem###.inf drivers

@JW0914 What exactly happens when you generalize OS? I cant find much about it at all. What if I were to generalize my OS, shut my laptop down and turn it back on. Would it just reinstall the drivers it needs and leave everything exactly the way it was?

@Rade I didn't realize the previous link was malformed - please see SysPrep and Generalize. Generalizing removes all machine specific info and drivers from the OS. Once the generalize function of SysPrep has run, it's best to have it shut down the OS, as the drive must be removed, or imaged when being deployed, prior to booting the drive.

@Rade (Cont'd...) Upon booting the drive, it boots to the specialize configuration pass of Windows Setup, and once done, runs the oobeSystem configuration pass, booting to OOBE.
